# Finding dwell time in R

Tags: r

I am struggling with finding dwell time in R, I would really appreciate it if anyone could guide me on this. 
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8KaY.png)

I am trying to find the dwell time for each type on a daily basis, is there any possible way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We cannot help with a picture of your data. Import your data into R and use `dput()`. Copy the output into your question. Show us the commands you have used so far.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it would be helpful if you could provide your data through `dput()` instead of using an image.

To help you with getting started, you can use `tidyverse` and `group_by` each day as well as the `Type`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Date = as.Date(DateTime), Type) %>%
  mutate(DwellTime = difftime(last(DateTime), first(DateTime), units = "mins"))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   Date, Type [7]
   DateTime            Type  Date       DwellTime
   <dttm>              <fct> <date>     <drtn>   
 1 2020-01-01 12:00:00 abc   2020-01-01 120 mins 
 2 2020-01-01 12:30:00 abc   2020-01-01 120 mins 
 3 2020-01-01 12:31:00 xyz   2020-01-01  59 mins 
 4 2020-01-01 13:30:00 xyz   2020-01-01  59 mins 
 5 2020-01-01 14:00:00 abc   2020-01-01 120 mins 
 6 2020-01-02 10:20:00 abc   2020-01-02  56 mins 
 7 2020-01-02 11:15:00 xyz   2020-01-02 285 mins 
 8 2020-01-02 11:16:00 abc   2020-01-02  56 mins 
 9 2020-01-02 13:15:00 efg   2020-01-02   0 mins 
10 2020-01-02 16:00:00 xyz   2020-01-02 285 mins 
11 2020-01-03 13:30:00 abc   2020-01-03  30 mins 
12 2020-01-03 14:00:00 abc   2020-01-03  30 mins 
13 2020-01-03 15:00:00 xyz   2020-01-03  15 mins 
14 2020-01-03 15:15:00 xyz   2020-01-03  15 mins
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  DateTime = as.POSIXct(
             c("1/1/2020 12:00", "1/1/2020 12:30", "1/1/2020 12:31", "1/1/2020 13:30",
               "1/1/2020 14:00", "2/1/2020 10:20", "2/1/2020 11:15", "2/1/2020 11:16",
               "2/1/2020 13:15", "2/1/2020 16:00", "3/1/2020 13:30", "3/1/2020 14:00",
               "3/1/2020 15:00", "3/1/2020 15:15"), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),
  Type = c("abc", "abc", "xyz", "xyz", 
           "abc", "abc", "xyz", "abc", 
           "efg", "xyz", "abc", "abc", 
           "xyz", "xyz")
)
```